# How deploy PHP Application in WebApp for containers

Tags: azure, web-applications, containers

I have a containerised PHP application (Symfony) in a PHP-FPM container. Currently we expose this website with a Nginx Server as reverse proxy and connecting via fastcgi to this PHP-FPM container.

Do someone how I can bring this PHP-FPM container to Web App for Containers Azure Service?
Do I need to included an WebServer to my container to publish the website? (something like Apache+mod_php?)

I believe should be someway to connect the Azure WebServer to my container.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You're only allowed 1 image, so you'll have to add a webserver to your existing PHP-FPM container. You've already got all of the nginx configs I assume, so try installing nginx in your PHP-FPM container.

Comment: thanks!

In that case I need to evaluate if better nginx+php or apache+mod_php for this case.